# jQuery issue with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using jquery click event to open fancybox and it is working perfect. I have added one textbox inside this `inline1` div but when I input something I can't writer anything.

**My Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").on("click", function() {
        $("#inline1").fancybox().trigger('click');
    })
});
```

jsFiddle: [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/1163/)

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: Just for the record : this `$("#inline1").fancybox().trigger('click');` makes the selector `#inline1` both, the target and the trigger of fancybox so every time you click on it, it fires fancybox over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the triggering of 'click', I managed to fix this by simply using the Fancybox API to open the Fancybox without requiring a trigger.

```
$(".fancybox").on("click", function () {
    $.fancybox.open( '#inline1' )
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/1171/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fancybox").on("click", function() {
    $.fancybox($('#inline1').html())
})
```

check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/1168/)

Comment: actually I don't wont to user #inline1 in anchor that's why I changed my code like in example.